# Chinese characters interline spacing in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have translated an app into Simplified Chinese. 
The app is using a UITextView and the contents of it is Simplified Chinese text.

I have noticed that (sometimes not always) the interline spacing is wrong, the lines are practically touching each other :

[image]

I am setting the contents of the UITextview via an attributed string that I create based on a required pointsize like this:

```
-(NSMutableAttributedString*) textWithPointSize:(CGFloat)pointSize
{
 UIFont * myFontDescr = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:pointSize];
 NSMutableAttributedString * description = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.exercise.descr attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:myFontDescr}];
 UIFont * myFontTips = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:pointSize];
 NSMutableAttributedString * tips        = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.exercise.tips  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:myFontTips}];

 NSMutableAttributedString * text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:description];
 [text appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n\n"]];
 [text appendAttributedString:tips];

 return text;
}
```

I am using the systemFontOfSize: function, I guess this should handle Chinese characters correctly? Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find out why but I implemented a work around by explicitly setting the interline spacing (only when language is Chinese) like this:

```
  //for chinese language we have detected a problem with the interline spacing
    //it does happen randomly, and so to workaround this we set the linespacing explicitly
    if ( [NSLocalizedString(@"__CurrentLanguage",@"zh-Hans") isEqualToString:@"zh-Hans"] ) {
        //make paragraph styl with interline spacing
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0.25 * pointSize;
        //font for description
        UIFont * myFontDescr = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:pointSize];
        NSMutableAttributedString * description = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.exercise.descr attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:myFontDescr, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}];
        //font for tips
        UIFont * myFontTips = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:pointSize];
        NSMutableAttributedString * tips        = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.exercise.tips  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:myFontTips,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle}];
        //add description then...
        NSMutableAttributedString * text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:description];
        //concat the tips (with 2x newline in between)
        [text appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n\n"]];
        [text appendAttributedString:tips];
        //return value
        return text;
    }
    //its not chinese, so do "normal" stuff
```